# python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
import datetime
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://magnit.ru/promo/'


def collect_data(city_code='2398'):
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M')
    ua = UserAgent()

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': ua.random
    }

    cookies = {
        'mg_geo_id': f'{city_code}'
    }


    #responce = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

    #with open(f'index.html', 'w', encoding="utf8") as file:
        #file.write(responce.text)

    with open('index.html', encoding="utf8") as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

    city = soup.find('a', class_='header__contacts-link header__contacts-link_city').text.strip()
    cards = soup.find_all('a', class_='card-sale_catalogue')
    #print(city, (len(cards)))

    for card in cards:
        cards_title = card.find('div', class_='card-sale__title').text.strip()

        try:
            card_discount = card.find('div', class_='card-sale__discount').text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            continue

        card_price_old_integer = card.find('div', class_='label__price_old').find('span',class_='label__price-integer').text.strip()
        card_price_old_decimal = card.find('div', class_='label__price_old').find('span',class_='label__price-decimal').text.strip()
        card_old_price = f'{card_price_old_integer}.{card_price_old_decimal}'

        card_price_integer = card.find('div', class_='label__price_new').find('span',class_='label__price-integer').text.strip()
        card_price_decimal = card.find('div', class_='label__price_new').find('span',class_='label__price-decimal').text.strip()
        card_price = f'{card_price_integer}.{card_price_decimal}'

        card_sale_date = card.find('div',class_='card-sale__date').text.strip()
        print(card_sale_date)

def main():
    collect_data(city_code='2398')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

никак не могу понять что хочет 39 строка

Консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\himan\Desktop\pars\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\himan\Desktop\pars\main.py", line 58, in main
    collect_data(city_code='2398')
  File "C:\Users\himan\Desktop\pars\main.py", line 39, in collect_data
    cards_title = card.find('div', class_='card-sale__title').text
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя видимо результат поиска - None. попробуй изменить код :

```
cards_title = card.find('div', class_='card-sale__title')
if cards_title is not None:
    cards_title = cards_title.text.strip()
else:
    cards_title = 'No title'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!